# How do I read all .txt in a folder into a thread pool

Tags: vb.net, threadpool

I am going to implements a thread pool to run my application. All of my content is saved under a folder on my desktop.

Each of the files are in .txt format. How can I read each .txt from a given folder and then put the .txt file into the thread pool / thread queue?

Comment: Wow. That is one vague question... To read the file, you need to use `System.IO.StreamReader`. There is plenty of documentation on that. From there... I have no idea what you are trying to do between having the read data and creating the thread queue.

Answer (score 1):

These would be good places to start looking: [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx) and [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx)

Sorry, my vb.net is rusty, but here's the C#.

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt"))
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessFile, file);


void ProcessFile(Object fileNameObject)
{
    string fileName = (string)fileNameObject;
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    // ... process contents here.
}
```

Your question stated wanting to read, then shove into the threadpool, but I would do it in reverse so you don't run out of memory.  Enqueue the file paths in the threadpool, then have the worker thread thread read the file.

Comment: On StackOverflow, a good way to show appreciation is to accept and/or upvote helpful answers.  I am glad I could help.